# Bash alias with nested quotations

Tags: bash, alias

how can I set up an alias for this command? (because it has multiple quotations)

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A some@place -W %h:%p"' user@xxx:/data/as ~/
```

Comment: What about declaring a function instead?

Comment: The [freenode #bash channel's "alias" factoid](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias), while the exact text has varied over time, is basically always some variant on "if you have to ask, use a function instead". It's solid advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use single quotes and replace each single quote with `'\''`.

```
alias XYZ='rsync -azv -e '\''ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A some@place -W %h:%p"'\'' user@xxx:/data/as ~/'
```

Or, use a function instead of an alias

```
XYZ () {
    rsync -azv -e 'ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A some@place -W %h:%p"' user@xxx:/data/as ~/ "$@"
}
```

It's more flexible and gives you a chance to parameterize the command later.

Comment: Might put a `"$@"` on the end of the function so it passes arguments through, as the alias does.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the inner double quote and quote everything with double quote because you cannot escape single quote but only double quote. (sounds a bit funny)

```
alias foobar="rsync -azv -e 'ssh -o \"ProxyCommand ssh -A some@place -W %h:%p\"' user@xxx:/data/as ~/"
```

You might want to check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280170) answer.

Comment: Sure, you can't *escape* single quotes, but you can always end them, add a literal, and resume them... and following that practice is generally safer, as double quotes have far more possible expansions that also need to be quoted within.